# JdbcPagingItemReader: PagingQueryProvider add a parameter value after the second iteration

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

i created a class that extends JdbcPagingItemReader. Inside i have this configuration.

```
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws Exception {
        setDataSource(dsSrv.getUserDataSource());
        setPageSize(Integer.parseInt(pageSize));
        setFetchSize(Integer.parseInt(pageSize));
        setQueryProvider(queryProvider2(dsSrv.getUserDataSource()));
        setRowMapper(rowMapper());

    }
```

```
private PagingQueryProvider queryProvider2(DataSource ds) throws Exception {
    SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean queryProvider=new SqlPagingQueryProviderFactoryBean();
    final Map<String, Order> sortKeys = new HashMap<>();
    sortKeys.put("ID", Order.ASCENDING);

    queryProvider.setDataSource(ds);
    queryProvider.setSelectClause("*");
    queryProvider.setFromClause("D_TABLE");
    queryProvider.setWhereClause("ID = '5d7031e6-10f2-4247-b581-17b2fe96449a'");
    queryProvider.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
    return queryProvider.getObject();
  }
```

The issue is that with the first iteration the query is assembled as expected:SELECT TOP 10 * FROM D_TABLE WHERE (ID= '5d7031e6-10f2-4247-b581-17b2fe96449a')

after the second iteration i have this query: SELECT TOP 10 * FROM D_TABLE WHERE (ID = '5d7031e6-10f2-4247-b581-17b2fe96449a') AND **((ID > ?))** ORDER BY ID ASC

> org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT TOP 10 * FROM D_TABLE WHERE (ID = '5d7031e6-10f2-4247-b581-17b2fe96449a') **AND ((ID > ?))** ORDER BY ID ASC]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; The value is not set for the parameter number 1.; nested exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The value is not set for the parameter number 1.

How can i avoid this?

Thank you

Comment: the sortkey with ID is useless but even if i sort another column this happen

Comment: If you provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue, I can take a look.

Comment: Hi Mr @MahmoudBenHassine, thank you for the answer. I think i resolved my issue:
I'm using a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor and the issue was due to the async behavior.

After using setSaveState(false) my job is working correctly. I find out this missing method investigating this bug: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3898
and the fix: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/pull/3959/commits/fa85ba54a354ff95722b80f34d295c429fc04886

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine In the fix there was a new test where "setSaveState(false)" was present and i had a brainwave. If desabling the saveState is so vital for async steps can it be explained better in spring batch documentation? 

Here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/index-single.html#JdbcPagingItemReader
It isn't metioned at all, for example

Comment: It is mentioned in the javadoc of the reader: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcPagingItemReader.html: `remember to use saveState=false if used in a multi-threaded client (no restart available).`

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine thank you, unluckly i found the javadoc after my researches. Anyway I have other questions related to this topic, is possible to ask you in any ways?

thank you in advance

Comment: Sure! You are welcome. Please ask your questions on StackOverflow or Github Discussions and I will try my best to help.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine I appreciate it 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77155817/jdbcpagingitemreader-questions-about-async-sync-behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() throws Exception {
    setDataSource(dsSrv.getUserDataSource());
    setPageSize(Integer.parseInt(pageSize));
    setFetchSize(Integer.parseInt(pageSize));
    setQueryProvider(queryProvider(dsSrv.getUserDataSource()));
    setRowMapper(rowMapper());
try {
  afterPropertiesSet();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
setSaveState(false);
}
```

For async steps is mandatory to set setSaveState(false) otherwise you can face issues like that