# JdbcPagingItemReader: questions about async/sync behaviour

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-jdbc

i have a question about JdbcPagingItemReader:
When we initialize the QueryProvider the method setSortKeys is is recommended to be used with an unique key constraint to guarantee that no data is lost between executions. Is it true for aync jobs?
Because for async job we set saveState=false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concurrency is not compatible with restartability. If you want to use the  `JdbcPagingItemReader` in a concurrent step, then you can't restart the job (correctly) in case of failure.

Comment: the setSortKeys is recommended to be used with an unique key constraint even for async jobs?

Comment: Sort keys are used for restartability. Concurrent steps are incompatibles with restartability. So sort keys are irrelevant with concurrent steps.